# Building docker container out of image with Windows OS, Java, Selenium, Jenkins from Dockerfile

Tags: java, windows, selenium, docker, jenkins

My system with windows 8.1 and I have the batch file in it which contains my selenium TestNG project.

1. Now in my office system, OS is Ubuntu and I want that script to be run in docker. For that, I have to build a docker image from Dockerfile. Dockerfile includes Windows OS, Java, Jenkins, Selenium, and the lib and src files of my project.
2. Can we install windows in docker container?
3. Can anyone tell me step by step procedure on how to prepare Dockerfile with those and build docker image from that Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this docker image for Windows OS (seviceCore) https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/

Java, Jenkins and selenium can be installed on top of that image and executed.

Comment: Could you please describe your solution in more detail and be aware that the link you provided might one day be out of date.

Comment: Pull a docker image for Windows (most probably the image link in my answer should work, kindly check). Install the required s/w (java, jenkins, selenium) on it. Then execute. However, using a Linux image in the first place should make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Windows containers but only if you are running a Windows Host. From a Linux host you **cannot** create a Windows container.

That said, the Microsoft [docker repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/) has some images to work with.